# Nginx subdomain running the wrong web application

Tags: django, nginx

so I have a ubuntu server that run two different website with two different domain:

```
www.firstwebsite.com
www.secondwebsite.com
```

But when I create an AAA record to create a subdomain with the first domain (like this)

```
demo.firstwebsite.com
```

If I go to this subdomain it automatically run the application website of my other domain ([www.secondwebsite.com](http://www.secondwebsite.com))

I tried creating a specific socket&service file for the subdomain for it but it still run the web application of the second domain.

Im not sure what is causing that and how to fix that? thank you

nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name firstwebsite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.firstwebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.firstwebsite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/firstwebsite;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/firstwebsite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/firstwebsite.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your current nginx config sampe

Comment: @akdev ok sorry for that, I updated the post

Comment: `demo.firstwebsite.com` does not match `server_name www.firstwebsite.com;` so Nginx will use the default server. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: even if a create a specific nginx file with ```server demo.firstwebsite.com``` it will still run the other applicaiton